# trying to scrape a text from a span element which inside a a-tag

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

```
<li class="ft_lt">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="active">Properties<span itemprop="name">(64236)</span></a>
<li>
```

I want to get the info in the span tag that is `(64236)` but I am able to access only the Properties-word

```
iso_class = soup.select('.active')

for i in iso_class:
    h.append(i.text)

print(h)
```

> 'Properties'

but I expect (64236)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS [attribute equals  selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

```
iso_class = soup.select('span[itemprop="name"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

bsobj = BeautifulSoup(s, "lxml")
bsobj.find("span", {"itemprop":"name"}).text
```

Answer (score 1):

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
        for i in soup.find_all("a", class_="active"):
            l = (i.find("span", itemprop="name").text)
        l = l.split(")")

```
    l = int(l[0][1:])
```